# $_POST not carrying the data

Tags: php

I have done countless forms on PHP and they (usually) work, so I am puzzled as to why this specific one wouldn't (especially since I am recycling some tried-and-tested code).

I have a fairly simple sql-generated drop-down menu, and need to select one name out of the list. I plan on carrying it over as POST, however the variable appears to be empty once I get to the destination page.

This is the code:

```
echo "<form action='step2.php' method='POST'>"; echo "<select id='producerselect'>";
    echo '<option value="0">--</option>';

$data1=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT producer FROM dbmain",$CONNECTW);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_row($data1)) 
{
    $prodname = $row[0];
    echo "<option value='$prodname'>$prodname</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
echo "<input type='submit'></form>";
echo "<p>&nbsp;</p>";
echo "<p>&nbsp;</p>";
```

In the following page, step2.php, I have the following:

```
$producer_selected = $_POST['producerselect'];
echo "You have selected $producer_selected.";
```

However, the only thing that shows up on the page is "You have selected ."

At a loss. Thank you for any help!

Comment: As a brief side note: you don't need to `echo` every HTML tag. More readable to keep those outside of PHP tags, especially since these ones don't rely on PHP.

Comment: Thank you @MariM - it's a vice I need to drop!

Comment: `<select name="something"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selectbox has no attribute 'name' so you can not post it:

```
<select id='producerselect' name="producerselect">
```

When the form is posting is looking for elements by name.

Comment: This did it - for some reason I had used "id". Changing to "name" fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could keep you going on. Happy Coding :)